# angularjs directive nonassign error for optional parameter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

During page compilation, angular is throwing the following error:

```
  angular.js:371 Error: [$compile:nonassign] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.10/$compile/nonassign?p0=undefined&p1=wlDragEvent
at Error (native)
```

I've defined an optional parameter (attribute) in the directive as:

```
  wlDragEvent: "@?wlDragEvent"
```

I also tried defining it with @ and =? previously but it didn't make a difference.

The directive template has a hard-coded value, "MoveCell" which should be okay, it's an attribute, shouldn't need a model, correct?:

```
   <div data-wl-drag-event="MoveCell"
```

First, the error isn't thrown for every row created (ng-repeat), I've used some console.logs to try and pin point the error but I can't find a pattern.

```
  <div class="row">

    <div id="container" class="col-md-12">
        <div data-ng-repeat="r in rows" class="col-md-12"
             data-wl-drag-container="DContainer" data-ng-model="moveData"
             data-drop-data="itemId">

            <div class="gridRow">

                <div data-ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'startIndex'" class="cellContainer">
                    <div data-wl-drag-event="MoveDaySlot" data-drag-data="item.resId"
                         data-drop-data="$parent.roomChartRow.room.roomId"
                         class="roomChartCell col-md-{{item.range}} dragCell" style="padding:0 1px 0 1px;">
                        <div data-ng-if="showOption(item)"
                             class="gridCell">{{item.text}}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

The js portion:

```
app.directive("wlDragEvent", ["$parse", function ($parse) {      
    return {

        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            dragData: "=",
            dropData: "=",
            moveData: "=",
            wlDragEvent: "@?wlDragEvent"
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            if (attributes.wlDragEvent) {
                scope.wlDragEvent = attributes.wlDragEvent;
            } else {
                scope.wlDragEvent = "";
            }
            //...
        }
    };

}]);

  app.directive("wlDragContainer", ["$parse", function ($parse) {
      return {
             restrict: "A",
             controller: ["$scope", function($scope) {
                          $scope.$ctrl = this;
                         this.moveData = {
                         from: {
                               scope: "",
                               dragData: "1"
                          },
                          to: {
                          scope: "",
                          dropData: "2"
                      }
                  }
              }
          ],
          scope: true,
          link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
               scope.moveData = scope.$ctrl.moveData;
               console.log("wlDragContainer scope: %O", scope);
          }
        }
   }]);
```

I've been looking at this for a couple of hours and nothing stands out. We're *locked* into version 1.2.x in case there is a suggestion to upgrade versions or if there is something particular that needs to happen in this version.

Thanks!

Comment: Updated, changed scope definition to use '@', error is till occuring

Comment: **work around**: I removed the scope from the DDO and defined/assign the variables with in the link. I'm not sure exactly why that resolves it - I'll need to read more about directives but I'll leave the question unanswered in case someone can provide an answer. I'm sure it will be helpful to others

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a hard coded value to an attribute with '=' (two way binding) specified, regardless of whether it's optional or not.  when the value changes in the directive, it will try to assign that value back to the controller/directive using it and will have nowhere to place it.  I would think that '@?' would work for you but if it's not you can try keeping '=?' and assigning a scope variable to 'MoveCell' and using that value there instead of hard coding.

Comment: Thanks @Austin, I tried that previously and again just in case...still getting the error :-/. It isn't happening for every row (ng-repeat), that is what is confusing me. I even tried removing the definition but zilch. Thanks for the response!